# "Tout oppose le"

Tags: grammaire

Could someone please explain how "*tout oppose le*" works in the following announcement:

> À l’occasion des élections européennes, le 26 mai, deux philosophes sont têtes de liste. De l’accueil des réfugiés à la gestation pour autrui (GPA), tout oppose le Français François-Xavier Bellamy et le Belge Laurent de Sutter qui se lancent en politique sans rien renier de leurs convictions métaphysiques.

The first sentence is clear. The second sentence mentions (1) the questions of the refugees and surrogacy, and (2) Bellamy and de Sutter who are entering politics, etc. But how are (1) and (2) linked by "*tout oppose le*"? Does it mean Bellamy and de Sutter are opposed to (1)? If so, what is the "*le*" doing there? I can't get my head around this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sauf erreur de ma part, le c'est un article définitif. Le Français...le Belge.

Comment: Tout [i.e. De l’accueil des réfugiés à la gestation pour autrui (GPA) oppose le Français François-Xavier Bellamy et le Belge Laurent.

Comment: Je comprends maintenant. Je vous remercie. Bien sûr, "le" est séparé et constitue l'article défini. J'étais confus parce que je ne savais pas que "opposer"  est utilisé comme ça. Je vous suis reconnaissant de votre aide.

Answer (score 1):

1. Both Bellamy and de Sutter are philosophers and heading European elections lists
2. Bellamy and de Sutter (**The** Frenchman and **the** Belgian man) have opposite views on a wide range of topics from the reception refugees to surrogacy.

The article ***le*** is not part of *tout oppose* (everything is viewed an opposite way by) but to ***le*** Français (the Frenchman).

Comment: Oh, I see. Now I understand. Thank you very much. I didn't realise that "opposer" can be used like that. And, of course, "le" is separate, I see now. Your clarification is much appreciated.